# flask_pymongo can't access mongodb with auth

Tags: mongodb, flask, flask-pymongo

I use Flask and Flask-Pymongo

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
user = PyMongo(app, uri='mongodb://username:password@192.168.88.29:27018/user')
```

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: Authentication failed.

But using Pymongo with same mongodb uri then work.

```
import pymongo
db = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@192.168.88.29:27018')
```

Comment: Okay. So take a look at those two URI examples and see if you can work out what the difference is. One thing clearly stands out, and if you actually searched for previous questions like yours then the solution will point to that very same difference.

Comment: flask_pymongo needs specific dbnames so '/user' in it. it is same pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@192.168.88.29:27018')['user']

Comment: i posts because of auth problem. when I use no auth mode. flask-pymongo works.

Comment: [`authSource`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#urioption.authSource) It's always been there and this is a case where you use it.

Comment: Thank you, authSource is work.